# Creating a workflow for an IoT project

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I was using ThingSpeak for an IoT project. I've decided to move on with Azure IoT. My project consists Raspberry Pi 3's sending data to an IoT platform using MQTT protocol which will be displayed over mobile app.

While using ThingSpeak, things were easier. I was sending data to IoT platform, ThingSpeak was storing them without me configuring almost anything and mobile app that I wrote was sending HTTP request to IoT platform with an interval. Then, I was parsing JSON response on mobile app to display important values in real time.

So far I've managed to send datas to IoT hub using Azure IoT C SDK. However I am very confused about how I am going to implement these on Azure IoT, what my workflow should be like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure IoT Hub ingests data from your devices into the cloud and then delivers that data to other destinations for storage or processing. By default, IoT Hub delivers data from devices to an Event Hubs compatible end point (these Quickstarts illustrate this process: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-node). IoT Hub can also use routing rules to send data to other locations, such as storage or a Service Bus queue. The following tutorial illustrates these options for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-routing.